# Can not see my virtual machines through the web UI

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am not able to see my google cloud virtual machines through the console web UI. However, I am able to list them using the gcloud console . My question is: Is there anyway to debug this problem?

Thanks a lot for all your kind help.

Comment: Hello! I'm working at Google Cloud Platform Support and I see you have a screenshot attached with private information such as external IP's and your account username. I strongly suggest you to remove the screenshot from the post and restart your instances to change the external IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue affecting some customers today with displaying instances in the console. It is now resolved.

https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/developers-console/18004